# Custom Section styling not working in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, section-titles

To add a letter in front of every section, I am using the command

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{Q.\arabic{section}}
```

This is working, however the styling in the table of contents looks really odd, since it appears the additional letter is ignored and the item "Introduction" is almost overlapping with the numbering (as can be seen in the picture below).

[image]

Can this be fixed or should I be using another way of "renumbering" the sections?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the tocloft package to increase the space for section numbers.

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\addtolength{\cftsecnumwidth}{2.0em} % or other better value
```